# Tensor calculation : find interface node using torch calculation

Tags: python, pytorch, broadcast

I'm a newbie on pytorch. I have a problem with efficient tensor calculation using pytorch. It is not easy for me to avoid using for loop.

What I want to do is:

There are `N` "guest" groups with `M` points with x,y,z coordinates. ( `G`:  `N x M x 3` )

There is a "host" group with `N` points with x,y,z coordinate( `H`: `M x 3` or `1 x M x 3`)

I want to identify points of "guest" groups(interface points), which are close enough(distance < 8) with at least `K` points of host group.

I hope to have list of indexes that can access coordinates of interface points using `G` (ex. `G[x][y][:]`)

Really thanks for reading.

Comment: the host have `M` or `N` points?

Comment: does the ordering of the points in each group is fixed?

Comment: Host has M points. Guest also has M points and there are N guest. Ordering isn't fixed!